# convention for saving files that are JS object literals

Tags: javascript, json

I am still new to Javascript and for a while was confused on the difference between JSON and Javascript objects. I have a file on my server that contains a JS object, e.g.:

```
{
name: "alpha",
value: 0.33,
desc: "capital share of output"
}
```

and I had been saving it as file.json. I understand that it is not actually a JSON. After learning more about the differences between JSON and JS objects I have the feeling that this is really bad form to save it as a *.json file.

Is there a standard convention for how to save JS objects (that are NOT JSON) in a plain file? Or is it just a file.txt and I am over-thinking the issue?

Comment: It seems strange to me to want to store this in a file by itself - unless you assign this object, what you have is some JavaScript that doesn't do anything. If you want to store or move object data around, why not use JSON?

Comment: @rom99 I get that this doesn't do anything. Ultimately I call it with an AJAX get request and use the object to dynamically generate some HTTP code. I had picked up the impression that it is bad form to try and edit JSON files by hand and that JS object literal was a better way to store data, but that may be wrong.

Comment: It definitely sounds to me like you should store this as 'proper' JSON. You are using the .json extension so anyone else reading the file would expect it to be valid JSON. When you call it with your AJAX request, I assume it gets treated as JSON even though it isn't valid? By the way if you want to check some hand-crafted JSON for validity, there are online validators you can use, for example http://jsonlint.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no file naming convention for saving fragments of JavaScript (note that your example is not valid JavaScript since, in that context, `{}` indicates a block rather than an object literal and the content of it is not valid).

Nothing in that example can't be expressed in JSON though, so I'd add quotes around the property names and then just call it JSON with a `.json` file extension. That makes it clear what it is.

Comment: What do you mean "the content of it is not valid"? In node.js I can read this from file, it is stored as a data structure, and I can use it in other code...

Comment: I mean that if you try to execute it (without wrapping it with anything else) as JS, you'll cause an exception to thrown, so you can't reasonably say it is a JavaScript program.

Answer (score 0):

```
fs.writeFileSync("myfile.json",JSON.stringify(myJsObject));
```

In Nodejs.

No Javascript object is JSON,JSON is a serialization format,just like XML.Valid XML has rules right? well valid JSON has rules too.The fact that it looks like javascript code is because JSON is inspired by the Javascript Object Notation. But keep in mind , JSON is only a serialization format.(though you can deserialize json easily with nodejs).

valid JSON would be

```
{
"name": "alpha",
"value": 0.33,
"desc": "capital share of output"
}
```

with the key quoted,in a text file for instance.

and the spec :

http://json.org/